# How can I replace a string in both directory and file names, using the Ubuntu "rename" tool?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rename

How to rename a substring in both subdirectories and filenames which are in a parent directory, when both subdirectories and filenames contain the same substring ?

In particular, I want to substitute "cam_0" by "cam_1" in both subdirectories and filenames.

Example:

```
parent:
--subdirectory_cam_0:
------ subdir_cam_0_image1.jpg
------ subdir_cam_0_image2.jpg
------ subdir_cam_0_image3.jpg
```

remate to:

```
parent:
--subdirectory_cam_1:
------ subdir_cam_1_image1.jpg
------ subdir_cam_1_image2.jpg
------ subdir_cam_1_image3.jpg
```

I used the next command:

```
find -iname "*cam_0*" | rename 's/(cam_0)/cam_1/'
```

But it only changes the name of the subdirectory and NOT the names of files.

It throws the next message:

```
./subdirectory_cam_0/subdir_cam_0_image1.jpg not renamed: ./subdirectory_cam_1/subdir_cam_0_image1.jpg already exists
./subdirectory_cam_0/subdir_cam_0_image3.jpg not renamed: ./subdirectory_cam_1/subdir_cam_0_image3.jpg already exists
./subdirectory_cam_0/subdir_cam_0_image2.jpg not renamed: ./subdirectory_cam_1/subdir_cam_0_image2.jpg already exists
```

Comment: Does adding a `g` flag, to replace as many matches as exist, help? That is, `rename 's/cam_0/cam_1/g'`. (Note that `rename` isn't a standard command, nor part of bash itself -- there's more than one version with different behavior -- so it's hard to be sure that advice will work as expected with your version).

Comment: (Also, some versions of `rename` will take filenames on the command line, as opposed to stdin; if you have one of those, `find . -iname '*cam0*' -exec rename 's/cam_0/cam_1/g' {} +` is liable to be more reliable, *especially* in the presence of hostile/malicious names, such as those containing newlines).

Comment: Are you willing to accept a pure bash answer, which is to say, one that *doesn't* rely on the `rename` tool Ubuntu provides? (If not, I might argue that this is more a question about `rename` than a question about bash as such; for future note, questions about interactive use of UNIX tools, vs questions about scripting, are often a better fit for our sister site [unix.se] rather than StackOverflow proper).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `g` in the end of your rename matching pattern to rename all finded matches.

try this:

```
find -iname "*cam_0*" | rename 's/(cam_0)/cam_1/g'
```